# Why my function get full height of div using javascript not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why my function  get full height of div using javascript not work ?

I tried my code but not work , How can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elmHeight, elmMargin;
    if (document.all) { // IE
        elmHeight = document.getElementById(divxx).currentStyle.height;
        elmMargin = parseInt(document.getElementById(divxx).currentStyle.marginTop, 10) + parseInt(document.getElementById(divxx).currentStyle.marginBottom, 10) + "px";
    }
    else { // Mozilla
        elmHeight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(divxx), '').getPropertyValue('height');
        elmMargin = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(divxx), '').getPropertyValue('margin-top')) + parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(divxx), '').getPropertyValue('margin-bottom')) + "px";
    }
    alert("Height=" + elmHeight + "\nMargin=" + elmMargin);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#divxx {
    height:20px;
    margin:7px;
} 
</style>

<div id="divxx">TEST AREA</div>
```

Comment: "but not work" doesn't tell us anything. What are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: in what way does your code "not work"

Comment: So debug it. Your browser has a powerful debugger built into it which is almost certainly telling you why the code can't be parsed / run.

Comment: You need to quote "divxx" in your `getElementById` calls, otherwise it will look for a variable called "divxx", which is `undefined` and probably giving you a reference error. But the answer by @T.J.Crowder below has a valid point. If you're using jQuery, just use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You've said that it doesn't show the alert, which almost certainly means there's a syntax or runtime error somewhere. Your browser's debugger can tell you where.

You're also working too hard. :-) As you're already using jQuery, why not...[use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)?

```
var eleHeight = $("#divxx").outerHeight();
```

And if you really need that margin information for some *other* reason:

```
var $div = $("#divxx");
var eleHeight = $div.outerHeight();
var eleMargin =
    parseInt($div.css("margin-top"), 10) +
    parseInt($div.css("margin-bottom"), 10);
```

[jQuery's `.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) handles the whole `.currentStyle` vs. `getComputedStyle` thing for you.

**Live Example**:

```js
var $div = $("#divxx");
var eleHeight = $div.outerHeight();
var eleMargin =
  parseInt($div.css("margin-top"), 10) +
  parseInt($div.css("margin-bottom"), 10);
alert("eleHeight = " + eleHeight + ", eleMargin = " + eleMargin);
```

```css
#divxx {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divxx">TEST AREA</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```